# Is it possible to auto-fill when aligning one item on the top right side with Flexbox or CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

First of all, apologies for my English. It's not my first language and I'm struggling to properly describe the problem I am facing. I've tried searching for similar questions, but was unable to find anything - partially because I am unsure what to exactly search for... I will include drawings to hopefully clarify myself better.

I have an application with a bunch of rows of content - it's pretty linear, each has its own `div` (I know, I know..). These `div`s are generated based on the incoming data, so it's not always the same amount of rows. One of them is a comments/notes section. I want to change it so that on higher resolutions, the comment section gets its own column to the right to make the most out of the screen space.

Now, I have managed to get the comment section on the right-hand side with CSS Grid. However, the problem I run into with this solution is that it still uses up the row space from the comment section on the left-hand side, resulting in whitespace. I know I can use `grid-row` to assign row positions, but since it is not a set amount of rows, I am unsure how to proceed. Should I write a JS function to add +1 for every new row, or am I overthinking things and is there a much simpler solution for my problem? FYI, I have tried Flexbox as well but ran into similar problems. I feel like I'm missing something incredibly obvious here, but I have post-covid brain fog and it's been a struggle.

[Here's a quick sketch to hopefully better show what I mean..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFHyk.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `grid-row-end` to a ridiculously high number, so that the comment section will always cover enough rows for the left side. This works as long as you have no `row-gap` because if you **do** have `row-gap`, there would be lots of gaps created between all the rows created from the high `grid-row-end` value.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
}
@media (min-width: 20rem) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

.row {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.comments {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 15rem;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">Row</div>
  <div class="row">Row</div>
  <div class="row">Row</div>
  <div class="comments">Comments</div>
  <div class="row">Row</div>
  <div class="row">Row</div>
  <div class="row">Row</div>
  <div class="row">Row</div>
</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! You have saved my evening, I truly appreciate you for taking the time to look at my issue.